# Constructing a string with new lines from a dynamic array

Tags: python

I'm having a tough time figuring out a solution to this one. I need to construct a single string with newlines that is built from a dynamic array. For example

```
mylist = ['first line', 'second line', 'third line', 'fourth line']
```

The single text string will need to ultimately be this:

```
preamble = 'My preamble'
postamble = 'My postable'

TEXT = preamble+'\n'+mylist[0]+'\n'+mylist[1]+'\n'+mylist[2]+'\n'+mylist[3]+'\n'+postamble
```

Here is the catch, the length of mylist is dynamic so TEXT must automatically adjust. So if mylist is this:

```
mylist = ['first line', 'second line', 'third line']
```

then my TEXT will automatically be this:

```
TEXT = preamble+'\n'+mylist[0]+'\n'+mylist[1]+'\n'+mylist[2]+'\n'+postamble
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: I'd look at using a for statement with the variables in mylist. Just keep in mind you may need to delete the last \n from the text string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mylist = ['first line', 'second line', 'third line', 'fourth line']
preamble = 'My preamble'
postamble = 'My postable'

text = preamble + '\n' + ('\n'.join(mylist)) + '\n' + postamble

print text
```

`print text` then produces the string in the following format:

```
My preamble
first line
second line
third line
fourth line
My postable
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `join`:

```
TEXT = preamble + '\n' + '\n'.join(mylist) + '\n' + postamble

TEXT
'My preamble\nfirst line\nsecond line\nthird line\nfourth line\nMy postable'

print TEXT

My preamble
first line
second line
third line
fourth line
My postable
```

---

To make it more dynamic, you can do it in a function, and call it whenever your list changes:

```
def get_TEXT():
    return preamble + '\n' + '\n'.join(mylist) + '\n' + postamble

mylist.append('fifth line')

get_TEXT()
'My preamble\nfirst line\nsecond line\nthird line\nfourth line\nfifth line\nMy postable'

print get_TEXT()

My preamble
first line
second line
third line
fourth line
fifth line
My postable
```

Comment: @ChrisHall, not a problem, not being mean or anything, could you explain why you favour to another answer whereas my answer came first? Is that something to do with style?

Answer (score 0):

```
"\n".join([preamble] + mylist + [postamble])
```

Comment: This is incorrect, consider if `mylist` is **empty**, your result will be missing 1 `\n` compared to OP's

Comment: that said, this is a more elegant way to use the `join` :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case your list contains other types than strings:

```
a=[10,11,12]
preamb='My Pre\n'
postam='My Pos'

Text=preamb
for i in a:
    Text += str(i)+'\n'
Text+=postam
print Text
```

Result:

```
My Pre
10
11
12
My Pos
```